# Clustering classifiers with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have let's say 100 base classifiers trained using BaggingClassifier from sklearn. I know I can cluster data using sklearn (eg using K-Means) but it's only for dataset not for classifiers. Can I cluster classifiers (from BaggingClassifier) into clusters? If I cannot do this using sklearn then are there any other techniques to cluster base classifiers?

Comment: What do you mean by clustering classifiers ? Did you meant clustering of output data from the classifiers ?

Comment: It's not quite clear why you are doing this but you can cluster either predictions of your classifiers or convert predictions to TRUE/FALSE and cluster after that.

Comment: I have pre-trained classifiers. Now I need to group (cluster) that classifiers by some measurement and select the best classifier from each cluster to predict the output and at the end I'll have number_of_clusters predictions to calculate the final result.

Comment: What is the difference between classifiers and regular data? You need to extract some property out of each classifier and create a new dataset based on it.